# How to fix 'Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js due to access control checks'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am using React to build a generic weather web app. Right now I am just trying to get the weather data for a city (ie. not doing anything dynamic yet) and logging it in the console.

I am using the OpenWeatherMap API.

However, I get the following errors whenever I call the API:

1. Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js due to access control checks.
2. Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
3. Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: cancelled
   I want to understand what might cause these errors and how to solve them.

Previously, I had tried using AccuWeather API but it gave the same errors.

However, if I call the API within the componentDidMount() function in React, it fetches the data just fine. The trouble arises when I try to fetch weather data on form submission.

Here's my main App code:

```
  weatherData = async function() {
    try {
      const resp = await fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=APP-ID');
      const data = await resp.json();
      console.log(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Title />
        <Form loadWeather={this.weatherData} />
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

This is the React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Form.css';

const Form = (props) => {
    return (
        <form onSubmit = {props.loadWeather}>
            <input className='input' type='text' name='city' placeholder='Enter City'></input>
            <input className='input' type='text' name='country' placeholder='Enter Country'></input>
            <button className='button'>Get Weather!</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: The `Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js due to access control checks` error message cited in the question has nothing to do with the request to `https://api.openweathermap.org` shown in the question. Instead, your code is somewhere else making a request to `http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js` and the problem is that your `http://localhost:3000` server apparently isn’t CORS-enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fully commit to one approach or use the other:

Basic React.Component Class example:

```
constructor(props) {
  //...
  this.weatherData = this.weatherData.bind(this);
}

async weatherData() {/* your code */}
```

Or, use the composure approach:

```
weatherData = () => {/* ... */}
```

Your composure is assigning a `function()` which re-binds the context of `this`. You need to assign an arrow function `() => {}` to preserve `this` as to not find yourself getting `this` lost.

The best way around this catastrophe of binding stuff is to go with the functional approach:

```
function WeatherThing() {
  const weatherData = async () => {
    const weatherInfo = await weatherDataFetch();
  }

  return (<div onClick={weatherData}>Do Weather stuff</div>);
}
```

I would suggest reading about [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) to make your code a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the weatherData to the parent component in order to be executed in the child. For this  to work just bind it to the constructor of the first component:

```
this.weatherData = this.weatherData.bind(this)
```

As:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   //blabla
   },
  this.weatherData = this.weatherData.bind(this)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the hostname of my dev env and encountered the same issue.

If you restart the browser or the machine, the issue should go away.